# Pop up should open when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

What I want to do is to show an email sign-up pop up when a link is clicked.

This is how I am referencing to the external sumome.php file, which contains the js function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.barcabyfans.com/wp-content/themes/hueman/sumome.php"></script>
```

This is what I am writing for the link:

```
<p>Get more awesomeness <a href="javascript:append_script_code()">here</a>!</p>
```

When the user clicks on the 'here' link, the javascript function append_script_code() should run where it is contained in the sumome.js file.

But for some reason it's not working. My questions are:

1. the sumome.js file is a WordPress plugin's .php file, so should I reference to sumome.php file?
2. Am I putting the `<script>...</script>` tags in the right place?

Notes:

1. sumome.js file is a .php WordPress plugin file. When the page loads, the pop up appears. I am wanting this pop up to appear when a link is clicked
2. You can access the plugin sumome.js file [here](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/948144e3)
3. You can see where I referencing the file and putting the link [here](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/9c0d652e)

Comment: which function is showing popup ?

Comment: please download this file: http://www.datafilehost.com/d/948144e3
and scroll all the way to the bottom till the append_script_code() function

Comment: Just include the JS file in your html/php file and code this for anchor tag
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="append_script_code()">here</a>

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is open a page which executes the sumone.js script. You can't just open a .js file itself.

Do the following:

1. Create a new page (HTML)
2. Include the sumome.js javascript in  the html page created
3. Link the popup as follows:

   ```
   <a href="http://www.google.com/"
       onclick="return !window.open(this.href, 'E-Mail', 'width=500,height=500')"
       target="_blank">
   ```

This comes in the script tage:

```
window.open("http://www.barcabyfans.com/wp-content/themes/hueman/sumome.js", "E-Mail", "width=500,height=500");
```

Comment: sumome.js is a whole .php file containing several js functions. How do I run a specific function?

Comment: Nope. sumome is a .js = JavaScript file which has some functions but they don't get called. What you need to do is described above. Here some information how to call a function: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Comment: My bad, sumome IS a .php file

Comment: does it work now? I don't think that sumome is going to display something?

Comment: not working. sumome.php has a javascript function which will open the pop up. but not working

Comment: yes, because it's in a function ( public function settings_field_site_id($args)) there is a javascript and if you don't call the function the javascript will never be executed. Why don't you just paste the javascript into a new file and execute it?

Comment: call sumome_generate_site_id() at the beginning of your sumome.php file!

Comment: I'm familiar with HTML but not with php or js. I'm trying that. will let you know. EDIT: what do you mean at the beginning? Can you please write all the code required in a separate file?

Comment: What do you mean at the beginning? Can you please write all the code required in a separate file?

Comment: at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

try this code. For example using open-popup class for the link

```
<a class="open-popup" href="javascript:;">here</a>
```

then, on js you can using selector "a.open-popup", for example

```
function append_script_code() {
   $("a.open-popup").off('click').on('click', function() {
         /*your code*/
   });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="runThisFunction()">here</a>
```

then

```
function runThisFunction(){

    //your code to show popup
}
```

Comment: The function is in an external file

Comment: no problem , if the external file is loaded, it will run.

Comment: The way you have included the JS file, it should load normally, just like you can add jquery from CDN sources. You can check in you page's source or console if the file was not loaded.

Comment: So am I doing this correct?

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.barcabyfans.com/wp-content/themes/hueman/sumome.js"></script>

<p>Get more awesomeness <a href="javascript:append_script_code()">here</a>!</p>`

Comment: Your adding JS file method has no problem.

Comment: If I am referencing the file correctly, and also calling the external function correctly, why isn't it working?

Comment: As I said before please try changing the href of your anchor tag as shown in my example and call the function directly in <a> tag